# How to get a WYSIWYG editor for post and page title in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg, posts, rich-text-editor

I'm building a site for a client who wants the titles of posts to look like the following:

**Photographer**:*Joe Bloggs*

Also 'Photographer' would be in a different font to the name.

Basically I need to be able to put tags around individual words in a post or page title so I can target them in css.

I have tried using the following snippet in functions.php to get a rich text editor instead of the title text box but it is not working.

```
function tinymce_title_js(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( tinymce_title );
            function tinymce_title() {
                jQuery("#title").addClass("mceEditor");
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "title");
            }
</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'tinymce_title_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'tinymce_title_js');

function tinymce_title_css(){ ?>
<style type='text/css'>
            #titlewrap{border:solid 1px #e5e5e5 !important;}
            tr.mceLast{display:none;}
            #title_ifr{height:50px !important;}
</style>
<?php }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'tinymce_title_css');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'tinymce_title_css');
```

When I inspect the title input box in WP it has the correct class of mceEditor as specified by the snippet but the WSYIWYG editor is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came to this question, looking for solution, so even though its old question there you have my solution.
1. You can go to file wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php
2. Find title input, and update it to

```
<label class="screen-reader-text" id="title-prompt-text" for="title"><?php 
echo $title_placeholder; ?></label>

<?php wp_editor( $post->post_title, 'post_title', array(
    '_content_editor_dfw' => $_content_editor_dfw,
    'drag_drop_upload' => true,
    'tabfocus_elements' => 'title-html,save-post',
    'editor_height' => 20,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'tinymce' => array(
        'resize' => false,
        'toolbar1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,forecolor,',
        'toolbar2' => '',
        'toolbar3' => '',
        'toolbar4' => '',
        'wp_autoresize_on' => false,
        'add_unload_trigger' => false,
        'wp_keep_scroll_position' => ! $is_IE,
    ),
) ); ?>
```

I know its not gr8 to update core files, but this way i found it working for me, so perhaps some of you can find it attractive...
Also you can always use it only for certain post_type 
Tested with wordpress 4.9.1